# Location for Installing Certificates

Tags: .net, certificate

I am just now learning about certificates and how to install them.

I am currntly following instructions as to how to design a profiling system 
that allows me to access profile information via SOAP envelopes. Accordingly, 
the instructions are asking me to install the aspnet_db and then the following
certificates:

- 1) IPkey.pfx
- 2) SubjectKey.pfx
- 3) LocalHost.pfx

I am instructed to use the MMC snap-in to import the above certs to the "Certificates (Local Computer) / Personal" node.

Then, I am told to use the FindPrivateKey executable to add NETWORKSERVICE.

It may seem like a silly question but, where should I be doing this? Since the instructions started out on the DB server, I installed everything there. Is that right? The next section of the instructions is entitled "Setting up an SSL Certificate" (using 
the localhost cert) and it looks like this is meant for the web server as it talks
about IIS.

Thanks.

Comment: sorry for the lack of clarity. I have edited my original question.

Comment: That's still not clear. SSL certificates *are* X509 certificates.

Comment: OK, I have re-posted with more detail. I didn't realize that SSL and X509 are the same thing.

Comment: Sorry but even from the file names it's just not clear what machines they should go onto. I doubt anything goes onto the DB server, the localhost one goes onto the web server but beyond that who knows. Please go back to where you got the instructions from and ask them for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type and purpose of the certificate.

- If you've generated a request for an
  HTTPS certificate from the web server
  then the corresponding certificate
  should go there.
- If you've generated a request for a
  client certificate then it should be
  installed on the machine that
  requested in, into the account that
  requested it.
- If it's a root certificate then it
  should be installed on all machines
  that need to trust certificates
  issued by the the CA which uses that
  root certificate.

And that's just the 3 most common scenarios, and even then windows has various certificate store locations you can put them in. There are numerous other certificates types and uses. You either need to be specific or talk to whoever gave you the certificates.

Comment: Thanks blowdart. I have reposted with more detail. Hopefully that helps?

Comment: Also, if for some reason what I have posted is equally unhelpful, maybe you could let me know what I need to do to help you help me? Again, I am new to this and appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Given the question, he probably means "ssl certificates", in which case: yes, only on the web server.

Comment: Actually, X.509 Certificates. It is not completely clear from the instructions but it looks like I am meant to install them on the DB server for access to profile information via WCF calls. Does it sound right to you that these certs should live on the DB server?